# How to create overlapped image span?

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring, spannable

I want to create a `SpannableString` with some emotions and text  like this image. [image]

Below is the method that I have used so for but it just attach emotions with text. Please suggest me how can I create such types of view.

```
  private SpannableStringBuilder getLikeCountString(UserFeedData feedData, Context mContext) {
        SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        int emotionSize = (int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.emotion_size);
        if (feedData.getEmotionTypes() != null) {
            String[] emotions = feedData.getEmotionTypes().split(",");
            for (String emotion : emotions) {
                SpannableString emojSpan = new SpannableString("  ");
                // Getting image based on emotion id
                Drawable icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, ContentDetailFragment.getLikeEmotionResource(Integer.valueOf(emotion.trim())));
                //icon.setBounds(0, 0, (icon.getIntrinsicWidth() / 2) + 5, (icon.getIntrinsicHeight() / 2) + 5);
                icon.setBounds(0, 0, emotionSize, emotionSize);


                ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(icon, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
                emojSpan.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, emojSpan.length() - 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                builder.append(emojSpan);

            }
        }

        if (feedData.getContentLikes() > 0) {
            builder.append(feedData.getContentLikes() + " ");
        }


        return builder;
    }
```

Comment: If you can find TTF is better to solve it in textview

Comment: Its default font of Android. Can you please explain how TTF can help?

Comment: some TTF comes with image and text mapping.  Suppose like button is mapping to `A` etc. You can create TTF also.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using individual `ImageSpan`s for each emoji, use one `ImageSpan` with `LayerDrawable` inside, one emoji per layer. You can do all kinds of overlaps with `LayerDrawable`.